# i am getting blue splash animation Problem in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am getting a blue splash Animation problem when I am trying to swift between in the list of an image of the PageView

but when I am using simple Image then its working fine But when I am trying to get an image from SQLite Database then I am getting the blue Splash refresh Problem in animation

Working Animation with asset Image => https://i.imgur.com/2XJDpRx.mp4

**Any help would be deeply appreciated!**

Below is the SQLite Database

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:scoped_model/models/person.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DatabaseHelper with ChangeNotifier {
  static DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper;
  static Database _database;

  DatabaseHelper._namedConstructor();
  static String _dbFileName = "animationWork.db";
  static int _dbVersion = 1;
  static String _personTableName = "person";

  factory DatabaseHelper() {
    // Singleton Design Structure  - For multiple use of a single Object
    if (_databaseHelper == null) {
      _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._namedConstructor();
      return _databaseHelper;
    } else {
      return _databaseHelper;
    }
  }

  Future<Database> _getDatabase() async {
    // Singleton Design Structure  - For multiple use of a single Object
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await _initializeDatabase();
      return _database;
    } else {
      return _database;
    }
  }

  _initializeDatabase() async {
    var databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    var path = join(databasePath, _dbFileName);
    bool exists = await databaseExists(path);
    if (!exists) {
      // exists == false
      try {
        print("Trying to create a new database cause it doesn\'t exist.");
        await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
      } catch (error) {
        print('Database could not be created at path $path');
        print("Error is : $error");
      }

      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", _dbFileName));
      List<int> bytes =
          data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: false);
    } else {
      print("Database exists.");
    }
    print(
        "Opening database anyway, whether it was already there or has just been created.");
    return await open database(path, version: _dbVersion, readOnly: false);
  }

  // GET "person" table from DB

  // The method below returns the "person" table from the database.
  // "person" table is a list of maps of Person objects
  /*[ 
      {"personID" : 1, "personDisplayName" : ""Meral", "personPhoneNumber" : "+905333654710", "personPhoto" : "AFH474JDFOWÊBB"},
      {"personID" : 2, "personDisplayName" : ""Özge", "personPhoneNumber" : "+905325474445", "personPhoto" : "AFH474JDFOWÊBB"},
      {"personID" : 3, "personDisplayName" : ""Semahat", "personPhoneNumber" : "+905325474445", "personPhoto" : "AFH474JDFOWÊBB"}
   ] */
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getPersonTable() async {
    var db = await _getDatabase();
    var result = db.query(_personTableName);
    return result;
  }

  // CONVERT  "person" table from DB to all Person list   => List of Person objects
  /* 
  The method below converts the "person" table - which consists of a list of maps of Person objects - 
  into a list of Person objects.
  */

  Future<List<Person>> getAllPersonsList() async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> listOfMapsOfPersonFromDatabase =
        await getPersonTable();
    var allPersonObjectsList = List<Person>();
    var reversedList = List<Person>();
    for (Map personMap in listOfMapsOfPersonFromDatabase) {
      allPersonObjectsList.add(Person.fromMap(personMap));
    }
    if (allPersonObjectsList.length > 1) {
      reversedList = List.from(allPersonObjectsList.reversed);
      print("database getAllPersonList'te if uzunluk büyüktür 1'deyim");
      for (var item in allPersonObjectsList) {
        print(" ${item.personDisplayName}");
      }

      return reversedList;
    } else {
      print(
          "database getAllPersonList'te else, uzunluk eşittir 1 ya da daha küçük'teyim");
      print("allPersonObjectsList from db = $allPersonObjectsList");
      return allPersonObjectsList;
    }
  }

  // ADD Person to DB

  Future<int> addPersonToPersonTableAtDb(Person person) async {
    print(
        "addPersonToPersonTableAtDb bloğundayım. Gelen personDisplayName = ${person.personDisplayName}");
    var db = await _getDatabase();
    var result = await db.insert(_personTableName, person.personToMap());
    notifyListeners();
    return result;
  }

  // UPDATE Person at DB

  Future<int> updatePersonAtDb(Person personToUpdate) async {
    var db = await _getDatabase();
    var result = await db.update(_personTableName, personToUpdate.personToMap(),
        where: "personID = ?", whereArgs: [personToUpdate.personID]);
    notifyListeners();
    return result;
  }

  // DELETE Person from DB

  Future<int> deletePersonFromDb(int personID) async {
    var db = await _getDatabase();
    var result = db
        .delete(_personTableName, where: "personID = ?", whereArgs: [personID]);
    notifyListeners();
    return result;
  }
}
```

below is the Animation Screen Code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:scoped_model/database/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/design_elements/size_config.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/design_elements/smart_design.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/models/person.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/utils/format_photo.dart';
import 'package:dashed_circle/dashed_circle.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
//there is some way to improve the way we have to do this skvkjsdvjdjsjvdsjhljshdljfhjdsnvjzvjzjvnjsljdvljsdlvnsdv

import 'add_contact_screen.dart';

class AnimationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  List<Person> allPersonsFromDB;

  AnimationScreen({this.allPersonsFromDB});

  _AnimationScreenState createState() => _AnimationScreenState();
}

class _AnimationScreenState extends State<AnimationScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  //
  int builtTime = 0;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  PageController _pageController;
  var heightAppBar = AppBar().preferredSize.height;

  DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

  List<Person> allPersonsFromDBReordered;
  List<Person> personsToPresent;
  int pageIndex = 0;
  int personIndex = 0;

  Animation dGap;
  Animation dBase;
  Animation dReverse;
  Animation<Color> dColorAnimation;
  AnimationController dController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("AppBar height = ${AppBar().preferredSize.height}");
    databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();

    _pageController =
        PageController(initialPage: pageIndex, viewportFraction: .51);

    allPersonsFromDBReordered = List<Person>();
    personsToPresent = List<Person>();
    animateDashedCircle();
    getPersonsList();
  }

  bool isInteger(num value) => value is int || value == value.roundToDouble();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    dController.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> getPersonsList() async {
    print('getPersonList called');
    databaseHelper.getAllPersonsList().then((value) {
      if (value.length != 0) {
        setState(() {
          print("setState 1 çağırıldı.");
          personsToPresent = value;
          print("Length of personsToPresent = ${personsToPresent.length}");
        });
      } else {
        print("database'deki personList uzunluğu sıfır");
        setState(() {
          personsToPresent = [];
        });

        print('database deki Person listesi boş.');
      }
    });
  }

  void animateDashedCircle() {
    dController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1200));
    dBase = CurvedAnimation(parent: dController, curve: Curves.ease);
    dReverse = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: -1.0).animate(dBase);
    dColorAnimation =
        ColorTween(begin: Colors.deepOrange, end: Colors.deepPurple)
            .animate(dController);
    dGap = Tween<double>(begin: 3.0, end: 0.0).animate(dBase);
    dController.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    builtTime++;
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    print(
        "Screen height = ${MediaQuery.of(context).size.height}, , $builtTime kez build edildi.");
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 7),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.all(SmartDesign.getPadding(context, 8) / 2),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.person_add,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: SmartDesign.getPadding(context, 16) * 1.25,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      print('Add new person tapped.');

                      /* BURAYI YAZDIN BIRAKTIN ******** */

                      Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ContactListScreen()))
                          .then((value) {
                        getPersonsList();
                        setState(() {
                          pageIndex = 0;
                          _pageController.jumpToPage(pageIndex);
                        });
                      });
                    },

                    /* BURAYI YAZDIN BIRAKTIN ******* */
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.all(SmartDesign.getPadding(context, 8) / 2),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.list,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: SmartDesign.getPadding(context, 24) * 1.25,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
          title: Text(
            'DashedCircle',
            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: PageView.builder(
            // clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            itemCount:
                personsToPresent.length <= 0 ? 1 : personsToPresent.length,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            controller: _pageController,
            onPageChanged: (page) {
              if (isInteger(page)) {
                print("integer page index = $page");
                animateDashedCircle();
                setState(() {
                  pageIndex = page;
                });
              }

              print('PageIndex : $page');
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: SmartDesign.getPadding(context, 16),
                      left: SmartDesign.getPadding(context, 6),
                      right: SmartDesign.getPadding(context, 6)),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      index == pageIndex
                          ? Container(
                              child: AnimatedBuilder(
                                animation: dController,
                                builder: (_, child) {
                                  return RotationTransition(
                                    turns: dReverse,
                                    child: DashedCircle(
                                      gapSize: dGap.value,
                                      dashes: 50,
                                      color: dColorAnimation.value,
                                      child: AnimatedBuilder(
                                        animation: dController,
                                        builder: (_, child) {
                                          return RotationTransition(
                                            turns: dBase,
                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                                  (SmartDesign.getPadding(
                                                          context, 6) /
                                                      2)),
                                              child: personsToPresent.length <=
                                                      0
                                                  ? CircleAvatar(
                                                      //radius: 90,
                                                      radius:
                                                          MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                                  .size
                                                                  .width /
                                                              7,
                                                      backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                                          "assets/images/blueAvatar2_Half.png"))
                                                  : personsToPresent[index]
                                                              .personPhoto ==
                                                          null
                                                      ? CircleAvatar(
                                                          //radius: 90,
                                                          radius: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                      context)
                                                                  .size
                                                                  .width /
                                                              7,
                                                          backgroundImage:
                                                              AssetImage(
                                                                  "assets/images/blue_avatar.png"),
                                                          /*child: Center(
                                                          child: Text(
                                                              'Initials')),*/
                                                        )
                                                      : CircleAvatar(
                                                          //radius: 90,
                                                          radius: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                      context)
                                                                  .size
                                                                  .width /
                                                              7,
                                                          backgroundImage: FormatPhoto
                                                              .memoryImageFromBase64String(
                                                                  personsToPresent[
                                                                          pageIndex]
                                                                      .personPhoto),
                                                        ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                        child: Placeholder(
                                            key: Key('colorAnimated')),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Placeholder(key: Key('animated')),
                              ),
                              //color: Colors.red,
                            )
                          : personsToPresent[index].personPhoto == null
                              ? Container(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                        (SmartDesign.getPadding(context, 6) /
                                            2)),
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      //radius: 90,
                                      radius:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 7,
                                      backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                          "assets/images/green_avatar.png"),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : Container(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                        (SmartDesign.getPadding(context, 6) /
                                            2)),
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                        //radius: 90,
                                        radius:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                                7,
                                        backgroundImage: FormatPhoto
                                            .memoryImageFromBase64String(
                                                personsToPresent[index]
                                                    .personPhoto)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: (SmartDesign.getPadding(context, 8)),
                          left: (SmartDesign.getPadding(context, 6) / 1.5),
                          right: (SmartDesign.getPadding(context, 6) / 1.5),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              personsToPresent.length <= 0
                                  ? ""
                                  : "${personsToPresent[index].personDisplayName}",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 23,
                                  color: Colors
                                      .black // Font size iPhone 11'e göre 18 bulmak için
                                  ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      //_buildCard(index),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }, // itemBuilder(){}
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I added a Video file to Show the error problem => https://i.imgur.com/ilrURiW.mp4

Comment: more likely be the time it takes Flutter to render the image (that small flickering animation). I suggest to use a Cache Image library to avoid that.

Comment: cache network image is useless because I am not using network image, so can you suggest any other package or anything else to solve this Problem....

Comment: cache images can come in many different ways, not just network, you can pre cache images even if they're uint8list and then used from the already loaded in memory ones. The blinks happens because those images have a larger size than the size you should be using and causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Every time your `AnimationScreen` builds it keeps on reloading the image with `FormatPhoto.memoryImageFromBase64String(...)`.

To fix this, when you load your users in `getPersonsList` and when you are creating your `Person` objects, you should call the function `FormatPhoto.memoryImageFromBase64String(...)` and assign it to `personPhoto` or a new variable. Then use that as the image like this:

```
CircleAvatar(
    radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 7,
    // or personsToPresent[pageIndex].photoThatWasLoaded
    backgroundImage: personsToPresent[pageIndex].personPhoto, 
)
```

Comment: Thank you for Quick Answer   !!! but can you please add more detailed code to understand it..

Comment: @SagarShende If you want me to provide more detailed code, you need to share your code for loading the person photos.

Comment: should I send you a Github repo??

Comment: @SagarShende you should update your question with the code for loading the person photos. I do not have enough time to look at your GitHub repo. Sorry.